# Does it make sense to work on DIMACS framework to test TSP algorithms?

Tags: algorithms, traveling-salesman, benchmarking

Are there any reasons to work with the [DIMACS](http://dimacs.rutgers.edu/Challenges/TSP/) framework, such as to test algorithms, coding, and heuristics of [TSP (Traveling Salesman Problem)](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/TravelingSalesmanProblem.html)? It is nearly 15 years since establishment of the benchmark in 2001.

Comment: You get a bunch of instances with known solutions. That's useful no matter how old they are.

Comment: In addition, many people know it and have built software that reads/writes DIMACS files. So yes, there are many reasons. You seem to suggest there is some problem. What would that be?

Comment: No, I don't raise any issue. All cases under DIMACS are solved. I think, working on those instances and presenting your contribution is limited.